# Does latex fix double whitespaces?

Tags: compiling

I'm copy-editing a long text with lots of double whitespaces in between words and am wondering whether the `latex` compiler will remove these automatically, or whether I'll need to replace them with single whitespaces manually.

If it doesn't (remove them automatically), is there a way to make it do so?

Comment: Well the answer is in normal text it will. However my first reaction was have you tried compiling your document to see what happened?

Comment: Any number of consecutive whitespace characters (tab, space) are treated as a single one as far as TeX's "mouth" is concerned.

Comment: @PaulGessler *Usually...* ;).

Comment: It will. It will even gobble line feed characters (or hard carriage returns) between lines of text.

Comment: @cfr I knew someone would come along and call me out on this. :-) I thought about hedging my statement but chose the clearer-but-sometimes-incorrect version instead. ;-)

Comment: @AndrewCashner I think that's the appropriate answer, here. :)

Comment: If you do wish to replace the erroneous double spaces, most text editors alows you to select the offending passage, and do a single pass of replace all instances of double spaces with single spaces. The replace text function is typically found in the edit menu.